# Dynamic CSS with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I've created a custom dropdown element.

The number of options it can have is based on a Database Table (I haven't created the Table yet). Like the number of options can be 4 or even 5 or anything for that matter.

I'll use PHP to give the number of options for the dropdown. Each of the options are in an `li` tag. The `li` siblings are inside the `ul` tag.

I have a CSS file which animates the `li` items. But instead of animating them all at once (in which case I would just animate the `ul` and would get the same effect), what I want to do is to animate them one by one:
Each `li` will have a delay which is progressive. For example if the first `li` has a `0s` delay and a duration of `300ms` then the second will start when the first ends, that is the second `li` will have a delay of `300ms` with the same duration. The duration remains the same, just the `delay` changes so as to give it a follow-the-previous kind of effect.

Since I don't know the number of options in the dropdown, how am I gonna do the same? I'm assuming it would require calculations but since CSS doesn't support it, there is no way to do it using native CSS.

My best guess is to use jQuery. Am I correct?

Comment: You would have to use jQuery. There is no way to do that dynamically through pure css.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see why this question right now is off topic. Also Please format with some newlines and ask an actual question

Comment: yep you have to use `jquery` . and to do it `dynamically`, what you have to do is, after you `bind` the data for `li` inside the `ul` with `php` or `any other`, in `document.ready()` get the `item count` inside the `ul` and implement your function according to that count. then it will take the `dynamic` count every time.

Comment: This does not require jQuery, see http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/ for more information.

Comment: @amo Lorentz - I know how to do this. Please post some example code with the animation working on some staticly built lis and I will reply with the CSS-only answer for a dynamic scenario.

Comment: That is not how SO works. Please post the code you have questions about and ask for answers instead of opinions which are off topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want jquery, but I know how to solve this problem using jQuery. This essentially adds a delay of 300ms per iteration over your options list that you fetch from the database after appending them to the parent list.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; //Whatever you fetch from the database
    for(var i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
     var new_item = $('<p>'+items[i]+'</p>').hide();
      $('#test').append(new_item); //Here test is the id of the unordered list.
      new_item.delay(i*300).fadeIn(300);
    }
  });
</script>
```

And you need to include this in your HTML -

```
<ul id="test">
</ul>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery, but the hope's not over there. PHP also works (Amazed?). PHP can not only be used to as a preprocessor for HTML but also for CSS. Have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) link.

Another thing is SASS or SCSS or any CSS preprocessor for that matter but that only works if you know how many number of elements (in your case, `li`) you have. SASS (or SCSS) have a loop construct called `@for` which can loop through a range of numbers and spit out pure CSS but still it requires you to know the number of elements to know the range.

Also what you can do is make a guess about the maximum number of elements and use `:nth-child(<number>)` pseudo selector repeated number of times until the maximum number. One aspect of this is that it doesn't require you to depend on jQuery but I won't use it.

So you have two choices, jQuery or PHP. Both works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in the mood to use jQuery, or want to minimize the use of JavaScript in general, have no fear! I recently read an article about it by [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/)

**What does this do / mean?**

According to this method, you can change the style of the sibling when you're not sure how many siblings the actual DOM will posses, as in your case. You will have to write some more CSS for it, but the solution will be much, much cleaner than JavaScript cluttering.

**So how does this work?**

An example:

```
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Logic here says,"if the list-item is the first child, and also the last child, make the width 100%"

**Now how to apply this in your own case?**

Simply apply a style for the possibilities in the css:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    transition-delay: .5s;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: how do you know the excact `li` count

Comment: You don't, but the impact of writing a multiple of css lines will be less severe if using jQuery, or what if a user is not enabling javascript? I would probably go for as much as 9 menu options, since more of them are very inpropable.

Comment: what if more than 9, what is your answer. and most probably users do not disable `js`

Comment: You disarm your own argument, the 'what if' clause. What is the chance of a menu with more than 9 items? And if so, increase it. It will still have less impact on the loading / painting of the DOM in comparison to javascript.

Comment: k, if ther so many `ul` tag, do you write another `nine`, and `another` and `another`. your answer is good, but not practicall with `dynamic` environment.

Comment: I can agree on what you're stating, and in that context, my solution will not be valid. I was merely providing one based on the given case :).

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ....

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  
}

ul{
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

<body>

<ul class="first"> see more
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>four</li>
</ul>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var thecount = $(".first").children().length; // at this point you get he binded item count
  
  $(".first").mouseenter(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<thecount;i++)
    {
      var needed = "ul.first li:nth-child"+"("+i+")";
      var thetime = 300*i;
      $(needed).slideDown(thetime);
    }
  });

  $(".first").mouseleave(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<thecount;i++)
    {
      var needed = "ul.first li:nth-child"+"("+i+")";
      var thetime = 300*i;
      $(needed).slideUp(thetime);
    }
  });


});


</script>

</html>
```

hope this will help to you.